# Create new Confluence page with Node.js

Tags: node.js, sdk, confluence

I want to run a script that will fetch information from a server and create a new page on Confluence with some of the retrieved information. I'm using Node.js. Is there any way that it can be written to create and delete Confluence pages? I've been looking around for a library/SDK, but all I could find was atlassian-connect, which is for writing Confluence plugins, not scripts that connect with Confluence.

Answer (score 1):

The confluence APIs are exposed majorly as SOAP RPC.
Even though they have recently come up with Rest API and JSON  RPC, It is yet to mature with full feature.
(https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started+with+Remote+APIs, https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+JSON-RPC+APIs)

You can go through the above documentation to see if method you require is supported or not as REST/JSON RPC.
If not you will have to take the SOAP route though it can be pretty cumbersome with js.

There are java and py libraries which connect to SOAP remote API. You may have to consider this route if REST option does not exist.

Comment: Actually the JSON-RPC API is completely 1:1 compatible with the SOAP API in terms of the features it supports.  I'd definitely recommend this as the preferred API if you're coming from a Node.js client.